# How can ı resolve React Hooks order error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm getting an order error because of the setResults state I call in useEffect. If I delete setResults the error no longer occurs. It doesn't matter whether I use it in condition as in the codes I added below, because I tried both ways. I get this error in the console;

```
  const [inputText, setText] = useState("");
  const [inputTextAPI, setTextAPI] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [fade, setFade] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    const ourRequest = axios.CancelToken.source();

    fetchHandler(
      "GET",
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SEARCH_URL}?q=${
        inputTextAPI.length !== 0 ? inputTextAPI : ""
      }&format=geojson&polygon_geojson=1&addressdetails=1`
    )
      .then((res) => {
        inputTextAPI.length !== 0 ? setResults(res.features) : setResults([]);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        dispatch({
          type: "ALERT_TOAST_TOGGLE",
          payload: {
            open: true,
            text: "An error occured. Please try again",
            color: theme.palette.button,
            cardcolor: "red",
            type: "error",
          },
        })
      );

    return () => {
      ourRequest.cancel();
    };
  }, [inputTextAPI]);
// where inputTextAPI is called
     <Box
                component={"input"}
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setText(e.target.value);
                  setLoading(true);
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    setTextAPI(e.target.value);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                value={inputText}
              />
```

// Error in console

```
  Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. useState                   useState
3. useState                   useState
4. useState                   useState
5. useState                   useState
6. useContext                 useContext
7. useContext                 useContext
8. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
9. useContext                 useContext
10. useRef                    useRef
11. useRef                    useRef
12. useRef                    useRef
13. useMemo                   useMemo
14. useContext                useEffect
```

I also called setResults without condition;

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const ourRequest = axios.CancelToken.source();

    fetchHandler(
      "GET",
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SEARCH_URL}?q=${
        inputTextAPI.length !== 0 ? inputTextAPI : ""
      }&format=geojson&polygon_geojson=1&addressdetails=1`
    )
      .then((res) => {
        setResults(res.features)
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        dispatch({
          type: "ALERT_TOAST_TOGGLE",
          payload: {
            open: true,
            text: "An error occured. Please try again",
            color: theme.palette.button,
            cardcolor: "red",
            type: "error",
          },
        })
      );

    return () => {
      ourRequest.cancel();
    };
  }, [inputTextAPI]);
```

What is the solution and source of the problem? Thank for in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your `useEffect(()` changes `inputTextAPI`  and also relies on it as a dependency. This means when your page loads the first it will run the setState in a different order to after it's loaded